# Order data with Firestore returns error

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm going to read a list of posts from cloud firestore but when trying to filter and sort I get an error.

This works fine and I get the data, but I also need to filter throw the age field

```
database.collection("posts").whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false).order(by: "createdAt", descending: true).limit(to: 10).getDocuments{}
```

So I tried to do something like this, but this returns a - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException error

```
database.collection("posts").whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false).whereField("birthday", isGreaterThan: upperAgeDate)
                            .whereField("birthday", isLessThan: lowerAgeDate).order(by: "createdAt", descending: true).limit(to: 10).getDocuments{}
```

When removing the orderBy call It works, but not the right solution

```
database.collection("posts").whereField("isHidden", isEqualTo: false).whereField("birthday", isGreaterThan: upperAgeDate)
                            .whereField("birthday", isLessThan: lowerAgeDate).limit(to: 10).getDocuments{}
```

Could this have something to do with the following quote from the firestore documentation? "Invalid: Range filter and first orderBy on different fields"

Comment: @AgRizzo that is the correct answer. Do you want to add that as an answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could this have something to do with the following quote from the firestore documentation? "Invalid: Range filter and first orderBy on different fields"

YES! The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) says if you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field.

You have `birthday` as the range comparison and `createdAt` as the order